Shed foundation in this location
I’m looking to build a shed on this spot where there’s a significant grade. Where the patio corner sticks out and down towards the end of the patio. Maybe 10x12. How should I do the foundation?



For a 10x12 the foundation is not required as much.  Can dig out the ground to level, build up the ground to level, use floating deck blocks.

Are you wanting the finished floor of the shed to be flush with the FF of the patio?  And do you want the shed to butt up against the patio retaining wall?

Ok. So dig to level and use a crushed base underneath the box?

Good questions @Huesmann. I hadn’t thought of making it level with the patio. I was planning on an exit to the lawn for an eventual riding mower, etc. but there could be benefit to having an opening onto the patio as well. So maybe make it that same height, but have a ramp down to the lawn.

@BobSpryn IDK if having it flush with the patio is good or not—that is mostly going to be a function of how much excavation or fill you need to do.  If your primary use case is a riding mower, IDK if you want the mower driving over the patio, just from a "scuff up the pavers" POV.  I would probably build the FF of the shed as close to adjacent lawn grade as possible.  And I think I'd give the shed maybe 6" clearance to the patio, just to avoid water possibly standing against the walls.
